# How to Apply Multiple Middleware in Same method on Controller in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
       $this->middleware('auth');
       $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }
    public function show()
    {
        return view('user.profile.show');
    }
}
```

In this Controller I want to apply both middleware on ***show***
method. When I access this method using normal login, this
displays content of view. But when I access this method using admin
login, then this method redirects to normal login page.

Comment: You can add middlewares via route too, and there you can set multiple middlewares. Also you can do this in construct `$this->middleware('admin')->only('show')`

Comment: Are you sure role middleware is working perfectly?

Comment: yes but i want to use in controller

Comment: i am also try this way also $this->middleware('auth',['only'=>['show']]);
       $this->middleware('auth:admin',['only'=>['show']]);

Comment: but its work only for one middleware not both

Comment: yes #pandhi is work correctly

Comment: I solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Hello guys**,
>
> I solved the issue.

**I just create one**

> **private method named as _show()**

which is common for both

> **public method named as show() and showAdmin()**

And

> **show() method for auth middleware** And
>
> **showAdmin method for auth:admin middleware**

**Below is my code.**

> **Controller page**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
       $this->middleware('auth',['only'=>['show'],'only'=>['showAdmin]]);
       $this->middleware('auth:admin',['only'=>['showAdmin'],'only'=>['show]]);
    }
    public function show()
    {
        $response = $this->_show();
        //Send $response to view
    }
    public function showAdmin()
    {
        $response = $this->_show();
        //Send $response to view
    }
    private function _show()
    {
        //Common logic
        //return 
    }
}
```

> **View page**

```
@if(Auth::check())
{--Goto show method via route--}
@else
{--Goto showAdmin method via route--}
@endif
```

I think it's helpful for someone who want to use middleware in Laravel 5.4

> Thank you

***Heart to try.it work***